# MVC: как указать относительный путь к ресурсам?

Tags: php, html, mvc

Предположим есть html шаблон /templates/photo.php:

```
<?php echo '<img src="/art/photo.png" alt="" /> '; ?>
```

В .htaccess описано следующее (всё кроме файлов и директорий на index.php):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Собственно сам index.php:

```
$moddir = "templates/";
$module = "index";
$route_array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (!empty($route_array[1])) $module = $route_array[1];
if (file_exists($moddir . $module . '.php')) include ($moddir . $module . '.php');
else include ($moddir . '404.php');
```

Так вот, всё работает отлично когда параметр один, скажем так:

```
http://www.site.com/photo   (путь картинки вычисляется из http://www.site.com/art/photo.png )
```

и она доступна и работает, а если:

```
http://www.site.com/photo/big (то путь картинки вычисляется уже из http://www.site.com/big/art/photo.png - что неверно т.к. всегда должен выислятся относительно корневого каталога)
```

Так собственно как в html шаблонах помимо абсолютно  прямой ссылки на ресурсы можно указать путь относительно корня?

Т.е. по русски независимо от URI, пусть src="art/photo.png" всегда должен оставаться таким. P.S. если написал бред - не пинайте, я только учусь! Спасибо великодушное за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть тэг [`<base>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)

[HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#the-base-element)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

то, что в нем указано, является базой для относительных ссылок.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/hptgY/